# how to saving a null child in many-to-one relationship

Tags: hibernate

how to persist the salesorder entity, with customerlookup null

the relationship is
in sales order entity

```
@Column(name="customer_id")
private int customerId;

@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="customer_id", columnDefinition="integer", unique=true, nullable=true, insertable=false, updatable=false)
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Customer customerLookup;
```

in customer entity

```
@Id
@Column(name="customer_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int customerId
```

i always having error :No row with the given identifier exists
since the customerLookup is set to null.
basically i need to save the sales order with no customer data by setting the customer_id and customerlookup to null (no changes needed in customer table/entity)

table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_so` (
  `so_id`               int(11)         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `so_code`             varchar(45)     DEFAULT NULL,
  `so_created`          datetime        DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_date`       datetime        DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id`         int(11)         DEFAULT '0',
  `walk_in_cust_det`    varchar(255)    DEFAULT NULL,
  `so_type`             varchar(45)     DEFAULT NULL,
  `status`              varchar(45)     DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by`          int(11)         DEFAULT '0',
  `created_date`        datetime        DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by`          int(11)         DEFAULT '0',
  `updated_date`        datetime        DEFAULT NULL,
  `remarks`             varchar(255)    DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`so_id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `tb_customer` (
  `customer_id`     int(11)     NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_name`   varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address`         varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city`            varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone`           varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `npwp_num`        varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_level_id`  int(11)     DEFAULT NULL,
  `status`          varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remarks`         varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by`      int(11)     DEFAULT '0',
  `created_date`    datetime    DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by`      int(11)     DEFAULT '0',
  `updated_date`    datetime    DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
);
```

thanks

Comment: If cutomerId is supposed to be null, then it can't be an `int`: primitive types are not nullable. It should be an Integer instead. But more importantly, it shouldn't even be there. All you should have is the ManyToOne association. `SalesOrder.getCustomerLookup().getCustomerId()` allows getting the customerId from a SalesOrder. So remove the useless referenceColumnName, columnDefinition, nullable, insertable and updatable attributes. And remove unique="true": if it was unique you wouldn't have a ManyToOne, but a OneToOne.

Comment: So are u saying that, customerId in salesorder entity should not be int?

Comment: No. I'm saying it shouldn't be an int. If there, it should be an Integer. But it shouldn't even be there in the first place. Re-read my comment.

Comment: i've trying to change the customerId in SalesOrder to Integer, and remove all the unused stuff (referenceColumnName, columnDefinition, nullable, insertable and updatable attributes. unique="true"). but still it doesn't make me able to persis a null child (in entity). maybe with sample i can understand you better...thanks

Comment: Remove the customerId field. It shouldn't exist. Re-read my comment, again. And clarify what you mean by "a null child". What is a child? What should be null?

Comment: I add the table structure in post, the goal is actually to insert into tb_so (salesorder entity) which is contain customerId/customer_id. the many-to-one is actually only for a reference in the jsp/view (i need to take the customer_name). but there are cases that i need a salesorder where the customer are not from tb_customer that's why i need to set customerLookup in entity into null. hope u understand what i meant with "a null child"

Comment: So, "a null child" means "a null customerLookup". Just do what I told you to do, and leav customerLookup as null. f you still have an exception, then it's most probably caused by something else. S post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception. Oh, and remove the "defaut 0" from the customer_id column definition. It should be null by default.

Comment: it's working (null or not null). Thanks. now i understand that a "reference" is actually not necessary. please make some post/reply so i can mark it as answered and u can get point :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a customer record in your customer table as `Guest` customer and then assign the ID of this `Guest` customer in your sales order. This is good because you will be able to have the stats of guest sales too.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but it's not answering my question, because i what i need is it possible to persist object when the child is null. thanks

Comment: if the child is referencing the parent using an integer column then no its not possible. the only best work around is the one i have already put in my answer. best of luck